Mobile push content-available value per OS
One of our customers wants to integrate marketing cloud mobile push with its App.
The app development team has requested an update to the push payload for each OS.

If a push is sent to an IOS device: Then needs to add content-available:1
If a push is sent to an Android device: No need to change anything

The only solution we found so far is to use the API.
To do that we need to:

Activate the journey - otherwise, there is no msg ID available
Retrieve the push msg ID manually from the UI
Retrieve the push msg payload using an API call
Add the key:value to the payload object
Send an API call to update the push msg

var url = "https://" + subdomain + ".rest.marketingcloudapis.com/push/v1/message/" + messageId;
var getResponse = HTTP.Get(url, ["Authorization"], ["Bearer " + accessToken]);

var responseObj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(getResponse.Content));
responseObj["content-available"] = 1;

var putReq = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url);
putReq.emptyContentHandling = 0;
putReq.retries = 2;
putReq.continueOnError = true;
putReq.contentType = "application/json";
putReq.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
putReq.method = "PUT";
putReq.postData = Stringify(responseObj);

var putRes = putReq.send();

This manual operation is tedious and unsustainable, as uploading a new version of the journey assigns a new ID to the push message, requiring the entire process to be repeated.
Is there a better way to achieve this result?
Some code to add to the msg body?
Or maybe something that can be implemented in the App SDK?
